# Limit of integral as boundary tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a positive and bounded function.

Is it correct that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_m^\infty f(x)\, dx=0$?

Or can we at least say, that this integral is bounded as $m\to\infty$?

I would try to estimate as
$$
\int_m^\infty f(x)\, dx\leq C\int_m^\infty 1 \, dx 
$$

for some $C>0$.

But now I dont know how to continue since I get the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: You write $\int_m^{\infty} f$, so I guess you are assuming this integral to be convergent ?

Comment: I know that the function f is convergent. Does this help?

Comment: I mean, is the integral finite ?For example, is the function integrable ?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is defined on a neighbourhood $[a, +\infty)$ of $+\infty$, such that the integral
$$\int_a^{+\infty} f(x) dx$$

converges, then the answer is yes. Indeed
$$\int_m^{+\infty} f(x) dx = \int_a^{+\infty} f(x) dx - \int_a^{m} f(x) dx$$

and by definition,
$$\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty} \int_a^{m} f(x) dx = \int_a^{+\infty} f(x) dx$$

so $$\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty} \int_m^{+\infty} f(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: I see. But I only know that the function is bounded, positive and convergent. Maybe I overlook something which follows from this.

Comment: For example, the constant function equal to $1$ is bounded positive and convergent. But how do you define $\int_m^{\infty} 1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an indeterminate form when you try to calculate $\int_m^{+\infty} 1 \, dx$:
$$\int_m^{+\infty} 1 \, dx = [x]_m^{+\infty} = +\infty - m = +\infty$$
Look at it another way: this is the area between the line $y=1$ and the $x$-axis, for $x>m$. No matter what value you choose for $m$, this area is indeed infinite.

Furthermore, the constant function $f(x)=1$ is positive and bounded. And for this $f$ you have that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_m^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx=\lim_{m\to\infty}+\infty = +\infty.$$